# AFNetworking 2.0 send multi images to server

Tags: ios, image, afnetworking-2

I want to send 4 images to server using AFNetworking 2.0.

I have seen many examples to send one image, but do not understand how to send multiple images.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet

```
 NSURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer]
      multipartFormRequestWithMethod:
          @"POST" URLString:[WECURLGenerator stringOfImageUploadingBaseURL]
                          parameters:dictionary
           constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
               [formData
                   appendPartWithFileData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.6)
                                     name:@"file1"
                                 fileName:fileName
                                 mimeType:@"jpg"];
                [formData
                   appendPartWithFileData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.6)
                                     name:@"file2"
                                 fileName:fileName
                                 mimeType:@"jpg"];
                [formData
                      appendPartWithFileData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.6)
                                     name:@"file3"
                                 fileName:fileName
                                 mimeType:@"jpg"];
           } error:(NULL)];
```